# Laravel. how can i improve this query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5

How can i improve this query
User model has an id reference to role
The query is done in a different controller then Role and User

**User::where('role_id','=',Role::where('name','=','role_name_1')->first()->id)->get()**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Laravel style you can use [query relationship existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations), so assuming you set up `role` relationship in User model it could be something like this:

```
$roleName = 'admin'; // sample role

User::whereHas('role', function($q) use ($roleName) {
  $q->where('name', $roleName);
})->get();
```

This will execute single database query whereas your code would execute 2 queries.

Of course you haven't written what you really mean by "improving this query" so this is just an example. You could also use `join` as in @Nuwan answer if this is what you need but in his answer he doesn't use Eloquent at all, just query builder.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with eloquent `join` query which will run only one database query to get the result

```
DB::table('users')
        ->join('role', function ($join) {
            $join->on('users.role_id', '=', 'role.id')
                 ->where('role.name', '=', 'role_name_1');
        })
        ->get();
```